# Is a complete bacteria simulation with an exascale supercomputer possible?

Tags: computational-physics, simulation, computational-biology, exascale

Will it be possible to simulate a complete (at least simple) bacteria atom by atom on an exascale supercomputer? or is it possible already today with the largest systems?

[Here](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/11/191114115845.htm), I've read that scientists can simulate an organelle of bacteria. 
For that, they modeled a system consisting of **100M atoms**. How to know which computational capacity was required for that?

[Paper](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3365009): "Atoms to Phenotypes: Molecular Design Principles of Cellular Energy Metabolism"

On Quora, there's an [estimation](https://www.quora.com/How-many-atoms-in-a-bacterium-say-E-coli) that an E.coli organism would have about 9x10<sup>10</sup> atoms (its genome size is about 4 million base pairs).

The [smallest known bacterium](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasuia_deltocephalinicola) so far has got about 112K nucleotides in its genome.

In 2014, there has been an atom by atom simulation of the [polio virus](https://www.quora.com/How-many-atoms-in-a-bacterium-say-E-coli) capsid on the [K computer](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nasuia_deltocephalinicola) with 10 petaflops. *To include enough water molecules to fill and surround the capsid, Okazaki and colleagues needed to model the dynamics of **nearly 6.5 million atoms**, which they did for a simulated 200 ns.*

A 2019 [paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/full/10.1177/1094342018819741?casa_token=0ARXWSLKuLUAAAAA%3AYQ9_9p5BuZtO0hqi_GzrBgArw6x2Ucl9gwMCyhEOuLtvThV_ZuIwvlWnVoox2mvoZ2mHi2S8zJhkjw) claims to simulate a non-biological environment with *a total of **20 trillion atoms** ... at up to 1.33 PFLOPS*, trillion is here 10<sup>12</sup>. The used tool in this case models fixed molecules, compare to more advanced and complex [ab initio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab_initio_quantum_chemistry_methods) simulation.

Comment: Related question on Matter Modeling: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/173/7. As you noticed, it can make a big difference whether you are considering an ab initio method (seems to be on the order of a billion atoms with HPC) or classical MD (as you found, likely on the order of tens of trillions for simple cases).